# Is there a specific way to refer to tuples that contain more than two elements?

Tags: tuples

When I hear or see **tuple**, I think of 2 elements. Are there specific ways to refer to tuples with more than 2 elements? Or am I incorrect in assuming only 2 elements when **tuple** is used?

Comment: Why do you think of tuple as having 2 elements only? Isn't *pair* the word for 2 element tuples?

Comment: In C#, a `Tuple` can have as many elements as you want.